# Can't upgrade Firefox with selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium

Temporarily I upgrade my sofware for automation web test.

I had Selenium 2.41 and Firefox27 working fine. When I try to upgrade the software, there is no problem about Selenium (I can upgrade to the latest release 2.45 and it's working fine with Firefox27) but I can't upgrade to any Firefox version higher than 29...and this is a problem for us.

I tried to run my test but I get this exception at some point: 
"Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear"

Any idea?

Best regards and thanks

Comment: Once refer this link, i hope its helpful for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633348/selenium-server-causing-firefox-to-crash/30639986#30639986

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm using Selenium's .NET bindings, not Java. I don't think that will make a difference in this case.</sup>

[Selenium 2.44 had an issue with Firefox **36**](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fselenium%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D8399), but this was resolved in Selenium 2.45. It's possible that Firefox versions between 29 and 35 might be incompatible with Selenium 2.45, although this is just a guess on my part.

---

I had an issue with Seleinum 2.45 driving Firefox version **38**: when instantiating the Firefox driver with no profile, an instance of Firefox would load and immediately crash to desktop; subsequently another instance would load as normal.

I found that the issue didn't occur when instantiating the Selenium Firefox driver from an existing profile, so my workaround was to create a blank profile, launch Selenium's Firefox driver using a *temporary copy* of that profile; then at the conclusion of the test, delete the temporary copy.

Try [launching the Firefox driver with an existing profile](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#firefox-driver).