# Selenium server causing firefox to crash

Tags: firefox, selenium

### Current Problem

I'm running automated selenium scripts every night. I just noticed that Firefox 38 is crashing and nothing is being listed in the firefox logs.

Clicking "Restart" firefox means that the tests run fine.

Is there anyway to debug and find what is going on with firefox crashing?

**Firefox error report:** https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/fdba810a-1980-45ea-b64b-0e8c62150604
[image]

### Current Solution

Since "Restart Firefox" is already selected, using xdotool this button is clicked by sending the enter key. (note: set appropriate display, `export DISPLAY=:1`). I am executing a bash script from cron that contains the following section of code:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
export DISPLAY=":99"    
java -jar /home/m/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "selenium/2_Suite.html" "test_results/2_results.htm" &

sleep 5
xdotool key KP_Enter
wait
```

### Update

Except for simulating the enter key to restart firefox and run the tests, I'v disabled all future updates on my headless automated testing VM using https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1003777 .

Comment: Downgrading firefox may help

Comment: @Saifur Have you had this happen to you? I found the crash report: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/fdba810a-1980-45ea-b64b-0e8c62150604

Comment: No. I am using Firefox 36 for all of my `Selenium` testing and yes, I manually had that issue and I downgraded. However, as you might have known firefox 38 is not yet supported by `Selenium`

Comment: @Saifur Thanks, that makes sense. I imagine they will probably release a new server... I hope.

Comment: Just clarifying something: except for the crash at the start everything works fine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium works on FireFox version 33.0 or below. Do not update your fire fox, selenium will not work on Firefox 36.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the .NET bindings. I never solved it, but I have a workaround.

I found that the issue didn't occur when instantiating the Selenium Firefox driver from an existing profile, so my workaround was to create a blank profile, launch Selenium's Firefox driver using a *temporary copy* of that profile; then at the conclusion of the test, delete the temporary copy.

In this way, you're still using a reasonably-fresh profile, and importantly *the same* profile, for every test.

The Selenium documentation has instructions on [launching the Firefox driver with an existing profile](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#firefox-driver).